# Change simple scroll speed on body to a particular class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

This may seem incredibly simple, but I can't figure it out. I'm wanting a very simple parallax style scrolling affect on a particular div, but don't want to bog my page down with some massive plugin that does far more than I want.

I found this code, which does exactly what I want, but does the affect to the body, and I want to be able to apply it to a class.

```
<script>
function onLoad() {

window.onscroll = function() {
    var speed = 8.0;
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = '50%' + (-window.pageYOffset / speed) + "px"; 
    }
}
</script>
```

I insert that into the head of the page and then attach to the body:

```
 <body onload="onLoad()">
```

Like I said, perfect for the body. But what if I want the affect to work on a class of "mast". How would I go about doing that. Seems simple...but I'm stumped.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just target the `.mast` element instead :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.mast').on('scroll', function() {
            var speed = 8.0;
            this.style.backgroundPosition = '50%' + (-this.pageYOffset / speed) + "px"; 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 but he said he doesn't want to use a massive plugin - by which I can only assume he means jQuery included since use of jQuery was not mentioned.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy - The OP did tag the question with jQuery !

Comment: Very true, I'll give you that one!! :D

Comment: My bad...jquery is fine. Huge parallax plugins are no dice. That said...while this should work, it doesn't seem to be working. Here is a link to my project: http://clients.paradigmcreative.com/vetro/about/

Comment: @HarlanBowling - Open the console on that page, and notice the `$ is not defined` error, that means jQuery was not included ?

Comment: I thought it was, and maybe I was duplicating it, so I took it out. I added it back in and still it isn't working. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, I don't really see a scrollable .mast element, but it's hard to tell what element the scrollbar belongs to ?

Comment: You don't have a `jQuery.noConflict()` line in there, do you? That would cause `$` to be undefined even if jQuery is included.